# Different results from same function with same arguments

Tags: c, function, variables

Here is a part of my code:

```
double interf1 = interf(ppp, numberOfPoints);
printf("interf (%e,%e)\n", interf(ppp,numberOfPoints), interf1);
```

The problem is that when I'm printing the values of `interf1` and `interf(ppp, numberOfPoints)` I get different results.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: What is the declaration of `interf`?

Comment: "Here is a part of my code:" how about providing a complete example that demonstrates the behaviour.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `interf()` returns different values from the different calls.  There are a great many reasons why that might be; we couldn't possibly tell you which one(s) applies without seeing the function's code.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a symptom of a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

This is a simple example of an implementation of `interf` that has a side effect:

```
int z;

double interf(int p, int n) {
    return z++;
}
```

Each call, even with same values returns a different result.

Other side effects examples include reading from a stream (e.g. file or network interface), the side effect being you are moving the position on the file, or consuming data from a network buffer.

Side effects aren't bad per se. You just need to be aware of them and if you introduce them, document them in the function name. Make it clear it modifies some state.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, there is an explanation for this (but the question sorely lacks appropriate information for anyone to truly nail it down).

**The method `interf` has some internal mutable state or dependency on other data which changes between calls.**

Alternatively, it's possible that the values of `ppp` or `numberOfPoints` are being changed between calls but this is much less likely. This would involve multi-threading given the context here.